# Limit the result starting from a specific row with a given Id?

Tags: mysql, limit, offset

I want to write a query to select a subset of a table, only starting from a given id.

I know about `limit x, y`, but `x` here is the number of the raw to start from. But in my case I want to start from a specific Id, no matter what its location inside the table.

What I mean is that the query below selects from row number 5, but I want it to select 10 records from row with id, say `213odin2d211d21`:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table Limit 5, 10
```

I can't find a way to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Note that, the `Id` here is a mix of strings and integers. So I can't do

`SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE id > (id)`

Comment: Can you paste your query?

Comment: Try `where id>x limit y`

Comment: @Jens I can't because `id` is a random number

Comment: you want to start from a specific id but your id is random? why your id is random?why not make it A.I.?

Comment: @Pantamtuy I mean it's randomly generated, In order to avoid some issues in my project with the UI and such

Comment: Your design is bad. Now because it's bad, you can't do what you want. You should never have random primary keys. There are many reasons why people use integer auto incremented number for ID. What you want to do is not possible with the data model you have.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible. By default, records in the database are not ordered. Without `ORDER BY` you can't expect the server to return your queries in any particular order. Since you are saying, that you store some kind of digit/char identifier as your `id`, **for which less then and greater then are not defined**, it is not clear which records "follow" your specific record.

You will either have to:

- Define another column to sort your records on, or
- Define a behaviour for comparing your ids (What is "less then"? What is "greater then"?)

That being said, you can of course define that you want to sort your id just like sorting strings! In this case, you can use `STRCMP()` to compare two strings. Your query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE STRCMP(id,?) = 1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 10
```

This will select the first 10 records, with id "greater than" ?.